# Rstudio cant detect git

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I trying to create a project from version control. However when I click git I get the following error:

`Git was not detected on the system path`.

Googling showed me that I to specify my git executable in my options:

So therefore I filled in "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe" in the field named: Git executable.

Having done this I still receive the same error however.

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: Does git bash working for you? if you have git bash you have installed git for windows.

Comment: Avoid the ugly "program files" location, install git in a directory where there's no space in the name (or enable the 8dot3 filenames generation on your disk, but it's a workaround)

Answer (score 2):

## Configure RStudio to use git

#### Open RStudio

> Click `Tools` -> `Global Options` -> `Git/SVN`
>
> If Git executable shows (none), click Browse and select the git executable installed on your system

#### Important:

**Restart RStudio if you make any changes.**

---

Read this for more info:
https://stat545-ubc.github.io/git03_rstudio-meet-git.html

Comment: He did not restart the rstudio. This is the important part he misseed

Comment: I got the same error on OSX because I had not yet agreed to the new Xcode terms and conditions, once I opened Xcode and agreed to the conditions, RStudio was able to access git again.