# Git is not detected in R studio

Tags: r, git

Via tools / global options I inserted my Git and SVN links. See example below:

[image]
I also double checked the .exe files are stored at the appropriate locations.

However when I create a new project via Version Control I get the following error.

[image]

Any thoughts on what is going wrong here?

Comment: Git is not in the system path. Check the system path?

Comment: Could you  please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: Git doesn't need to be on the system path, as noted in the dialog window. Maybe a simple re-start is needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rstudio cant detect git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409654/rstudio-cant-detect-git)